# How to point to a class method in fortran?

Tags: fortran, function-pointers

I have a module that defines a class with some attributes and a method (`proc1`) which is a function. Another module defines a function (`proc2`) that evaluates a function with one argument, given a pointer to that function and the argument. In the main program, I would like to define a function pointer (`fun`) which points to the class' method (`proc1`) such that evaluating `fun(x)` would be equivalent to evaluating `obj1 % proc1(x)`. Is that possible?

My compiler, gfortran 7.3, complains that

> Expected argument list at (1)

with the syntax below.

```
module objmod
   implicit none
   ! object with some data and a method
   type obj 
      real                  :: a, b, c
   contains
      procedure, pass(self) :: proc1
   end type obj

contains
   ! method which uses object and a variable
   pure real function proc1(self, var) 
      class(obj), intent(in) :: self
      real, intent(in)       :: var
      proc1 = var * (self % a + self % b + self % c)
   end function proc1

end module objmod

module funmod
   implicit none

contains
   ! function that evaluates fun(a), or does more complicated stuff
   real function proc2(funptr, a)
      procedure(real), pointer :: funptr
      real, intent(in)         :: a
      proc2 = funptr(a)
   end function proc2

end module funmod

program funPtr

   use objmod
   use funmod

   implicit none

   type(obj)                :: obj1
   real                     :: a, x
   procedure(real), pointer :: fun

   obj1 % a =  1.0
   obj1 % b =  2.0
   obj1 % c =  3.0
   a        = -1.5
   fun => obj1 % proc1 ! function pointer to fun(x) = proc1(obj1, x)

   x = proc2(fun, a)

   print *, x
end program funPtr
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't do this. The standard says, for a proc-target of pointer assignment:

> C1030 (R1040) A procedure-name shall be the name of an internal,
>   module, or dummy procedure, a procedure pointer, a specific intrinsic
>   function listed in Table 16.2, or an external procedure that is
>   accessed by use or host association, referenced in the scoping unit as
>   a procedure, or that has the EXTERNAL attribute.

In your example, `obj1%proc1` is none of these. You COULD pointer assign to `proc1` (that is, the actual procedure and not the type component) if you gave `fun` an explicit interface. Of course, you lose the passed object aspect if you do this.

The issue is that a function pointer doesn't have the context of the type-bound procedure.

Comment: With 'that is, the actual procedure and not the type component' I assume you mean _binding_?  `proc1` isn't a component.

Comment: It is, sort of - it's a type-bound procedure and is referenced as if it were a component. But, point taken.

Comment: I am trying the same thing, i.e., rename a class method so that I can use it as a usual function. It is disappointing to know that "a function pointer doesn't have the context of the type-bound procedure."